# How to pass numpy 2-dim array to C functon

Tags: python, c, arrays, numpy, ctypes

I have this interface in my library.

```
extern "C" {
    Demodulator<double>* Demodulator_new_double(int rows, int cols);

    double * demodulateDoubleMatrix(Demodulator<double>* demodulator, double * input, int rows, int columns);
}
```

The only way I know to pass numpy objects is by creating something like that using numpy.ctypes.

```
array_2d_double = npct.ndpointer(dtype=numpy.float64, ndim=2, flags='C_CONTIGUOUS')


self.lib.demodulateDoubleMatrix.argtypes = [ctypes.POINTER, array_2d_double, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int]
        self.lib.demodulateDoubleMatrix.restype = array_2d_double
```

But I need to set first argument to a pointer to object, which I don't know how to do.

Comment: Using the type returned by `ndpointer` is correct for `argtypes`. But you'll need to also specify the shape to use it as a `restype`. If that's inconvenient because the array dimensions are dynamic, then use `c_double_p = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double)` as the result type, and create the array manually via `npct.as_array(result, shape)`.

Comment: Well, thanks but it seems to work with casting Demodulator to void *

Comment: The NumPy array created with `as_array` does not own the memory, so garbage collecting the NumPy array won't `free` that memory. Presumably `demodulateDoubleMatrix` allocated it and has a corresponding function to `free` it?